# Access a property of an object as key in where clause in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'll start directly off with my example. The thing is, I have a couple of `hasMany` and `belongsTo` relationships and I'd like to access a property of one of the returned object as a key in a where clause.
Let's say I have a model named `Price` and it has three `belongsTo` connections to three models named `profileSystem`, `profileType` and `colorGroup`. Each of my three other models have a `hasMany` connection to the `Price` model.
So if I have an instance of my `profileType` model, I'd like to call it's price where accordingly the `profileSystem` and the `colorGroup` parents will have some certain values. Example that works:

```
App\ProfileType::find(1) 
                -> prices -> where('profileType', App\ProfileType::find(1))
                -> where('colorGroup', App\ColorGroup::find(1))
                -> first()->value;
```

As you can see, the comparison here works directly with the whole instances of the `colorGroup` and `profileType` models that belong with the `Price` model. What I'd like to do is no to compare the whole models, but only a single property, like so:

```
->where('colorGroup->id', 1)
```

or

```
->where('colorGroup->id', App\ColorGroup::find(1) -> id)
```

The question is all syntax that I'm not common with in laravel. I also couldn't find anything in the documentation. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes) for each of these:

```
class ColorGroup {

    public function scopeColor($query, $color)
    {
        return $query->where('id', $color);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the best method to access each property of the `colorGroup` parent model is to write a scope for it? Because there are plenty. And the case is global, not only for that model. Thanks for the feedback though!

Answer (score 0):

If your price belongs to a colourGroup, it means that you have some kind of foreign key in your prices table "eg colour_group_id". Therefore, you should just do something like

```
->where('colour_group_id', $acolourgroup->id)
```

If it understood it right, you will get what you want

---

EDIT :

You can access to a relationship foreign key with $instance->relation()->getForeignKey();

So what I would to is make a scope like that :

```
public function scopeWhereRelationship($query, $r){
    return $query->where($this->relationship()->getForeignKey(), $r->id);
}
```

But I'm not really sure that it is what you want

---

EDIT 2 :

You can easily generalize the scope I gave you. For example, you can add the scope to your root model (a class that every model will extend) and add the name of the relationship as a parameter. For example :

```
public function scopeWhereBelongsTo($query, $relationship, $instance)
{
    $relationship = $this->{$relationship}();
    return $query->where($relationship->getForeignKey(), $instance->getAttribute($relationship->getOwnerKey()));
}
```

Now, you have on every model a scope that you can call like this :

```
Model::whereBelongsTo('thenameofyourrelationship', $theinstance);
```

A little bit of an explanation :

```
$this->{$relationship}()
```

This gets the relationship, aka the BelongsTo class representing the relationship.

With `$relationship->getForeignKey()` you then get the name of the foreign key.

With `$relationship->getOwnerKey()` you get the name of the owner key, that is the field that is used in the second table (the one the model belongs to).

With `$instance->getAttribute($relationship->getOwnerKey())` you then get the value of the owner key.

Comment: It surely does, but the thing is I want to access the property of my model, not to have to work with the column names. Because otherwise it's a huge mess.

Comment: It is, but the question is that I'll have to scope each property separately in the model... Isn't there any simpler method?

Answer (score 0):

You see, what I actually needed appeared to be the `whereHas` function!
So instead of my thought up suggestion like `->where('colorGroup->id', 1)` the solution looks like

```
->whereHas('colorGroup', function($q){ 
    $q->where('id', 1);
})->get();
```